# How exactly is the "effectiveness" in the Moderna and Pfizer vaccine trials estimated?

Tags: probability, relative-risk

As in the title. Is this "a risk ratio"? How is it calculated, if you could provide an example with numbers for both trials, please? I am not a statistician, but I am familiar with the binomial distribution - I suppose it is used here to calculate the confidence intervals?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Moderna

Based on the [press release](https://investors.modernatx.com/news-releases/news-release-details/modernas-covid-19-vaccine-candidate-meets-its-primary-efficacy) we can assume that there were **30 000 patients total** and observed were **90 infections among placebo** and **5 infections among the vaccinated group**.

Let's assume that the vaccine group and placebo group were each of the same size 15 000.

So, calculated on the back of an envelope, instead of 90 infections you got 5 infections. The reduction due to the vaccine is 85 out of 90 patients that did not get infected (without vaccine 90 get infected with vaccine 5 get infected, so presumably the vaccine reduced it from 90 down to 5). This is the $85/90 \approx 94.4 \%$ that is the number you see in the news.

- This would normally need to be adjusted. The groups may not have been the same sizes and the people may not have been exposed at the same time (you do not get everybody vaccinated at exactly the same time). So eventually you will be doing some more complicated computation of the risk and based on the ratio of those figures you get to a more exact figure (but the on the back of an envelope calculation will be reasonably close).
- In addition, the $94.4\%$ is just a point estimate. Normally a range of confidence is given for an estimate ([confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)). Roughly speaking this is a measure for how accurate/certain the measurement/estimate is. It gives some boundaries for failure of the estimate (typical are 95% boundaries).

  One way to compute the confidence interval for ratio's is to express it [in terms of log odds](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1127651/) apply an approximation formula for the error use that to express the interval and then convert back to ratio's. This would give a  $95\%$ confidence interval between $88.0\%$ and $97.8\%$ for the effectiveness.

  $$\begin{array}{} \text{log_odds} &=& \log \frac{5}{90} \approx -2.89\\
     \text{S.E.}_\text{log_odds} &\approx& \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{90}+\frac{1}{14995}+\frac{1}{14910}} \approx 0.460\\
     CI_{95\%}(\text{log_odds})  &\approx& \text{log_odds}-1.96\text{S.E.}_\text{log_odds} \, , \, \text{log_odds}+1.96\text{S.E.}_\text{log_odds}\\ & \approx &-3.79,-1.99 \\
     CI_{95\%}(\text{odds})  &\approx&  0.0225,\ 0.137    \\
       CI_{95\%}(\text{effectivity})  &=& \frac{1}{1+CI_{95\%}(\text{odds})} \\&\approx&  88.0 \%,\ 97.8 \% \end{array}$$

These computations assume ideal situations (as if the numbers 5 and 90 stem from nicely understood causes for the variations). The assumption is not an interference that breaks the statistical model. E.g. patients that got vaccinated and had fever or other symptoms afterward may have been distancing more because of that. For them, the exposure is less and that is not taken into account in the on the back of the envelope calculation. In addition, this relates to effectivity for the total period (in which the infection pressure may not have been equally distributed). Based on these simple figures, we can not say with the same accuracy how effective the vaccination is as a function of time (especially the question whether the immunity decreases over time).

Comment: Thank you very much for so detailed and easy answer. Now it's all clear to me!

Comment: I believe it was 95 infections in total, see https://investors.modernatx.com/news-releases/news-release-details/modernas-covid-19-vaccine-candidate-meets-its-primary-efficacy. Efficacy seems to be computed as 1-5/90, which - not that the difference matters quantitatively - also produces the published 94.5%, see http://skranz.github.io/r/2020/11/10/CovidVaccine.html.

Comment: @ChristophHanck I took it from this news coverage  https://www.statnews.com/2020/11/16/modernas-covid-19-vaccine-is-strongly-effective-early-look-at-data-show/ which have mixed up the numbers.

Comment: Anyone can refer to a paper or study?  Have they made anything available?

Comment: Pfizer has their validation protocol (including the statistical background) posted on their [website](https://www.pfizer.com/science/coronavirus) [Direct Link](https://pfe-pfizercom-d8-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/2020-11/C4591001_Clinical_Protocol_Nov2020.pdf)

Comment: Most interesting statistical stuff is on pages 99-100 and 111-113.

Comment: See also this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496774/ about the statistical stuff in Pfizer's protocol

Comment: could you please explain why you can compute the s.e. for the log odds as a sum of the four terms? This reminds me of a first order Taylor expansion, but I don't understand which function is being expanded in a Taylor series. I can ask a new question if you prefer.

Comment: Also, I think the last formula is wrong. $\text{VE} = 1- \text{odds} \implies CI_{95\%}(\text{VE})  = 1-CI_{95\%}(\text{odds}) \approx  86.3 \%,\ 97.7\% $

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: Why is the efficiency calculated this way? I mean, why dividing the group into two as placebo and vaccinated an then taking that ratio? Why can't we just vaccinate all the volunteers and take the proportion of disinfected to the total as the efficiency ratio? Is there a theoretical basis for the calculation that you mentioned?

Comment: @Ashok the efficacy is a number that expresses how the vaccine works in comparison to a situation without a vaccine. In order to be able to compute such a number, you need to know what happens in both situations and therefore you have two groups in the study. You are right it can be done in [multiple other ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_study_design#Treatment_studies), but this way (a randomized controlled trial) will have the least bias.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: Thanks. Is there any pointer for the last point?

Comment: @Ashok the other types of study's are being done during the commercial phase of the vaccine. The effects of the vaccine are still being monitored and measured but without the clear comparison of a placebo group.